# How do I check if video has played for 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, video

I am building an educational website in which users watch tutorial but I need to get number of views. How do I check if the video have played for 2 minutes

```
 const video = document.getElementById("video");
video.onplaying = function () {

        if(video.readyState > 0) {
            var minutes = parseInt(video.duration / 60, 10);
            var seconds = video.duration % 60;
            console.log(seconds);
            clearInterval(i);
        }
};
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `ondurationchange` event. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_durationchange.asp

Comment: After video started to play use setInterval by calling callback every second, then check if video.currentTime more or equal to 2 mins.